# Word for space with too few people in it

Tags: single-word-requests

If being crowded is the experience of feeling as if too many people are in a room of a given size, what is the opposite of that? Think 2 people alone in a fire hall or even a warehouse. Sometimes it can produce a similar discomfort. Is there a word for this?

I'm not against words that invoke a sense of awe upon entering a large room, but discomfort is closer to what I'm looking for connotationally. Perhaps something more along the lines of feeling exposed.

As an example: "The room was gigantic. We both felt so ____."

Comment: Single word requests require an example sentence showing how the word will be used. Voting to close until this is fixed.

Comment: The room felt empty (or synonym), but the people in it felt lonely (or synonym).

Comment: For your new example: "Isolated" ?

Comment: 'Insignificant' may well apply, but  is hardly an opposite of 'oppressed'.

Comment: **agoraphobic** maybe?

Comment: Insignificant and kenophobic are the closest here

Comment: There is more than one reason for discomfort in a situation such as you describe.  I like @Hellion's ***isolated*** as one of them.  I was about to say ***exposed***, myself, until I saw that you actually use that in the question.  How, then, does it it not serve your purpose?

Comment: Mountain climbers speak of being exposed in just this way. "It's not that technical, but the exposure is huge." It refers to a sense of vulnerability that is exacerbated by an awareness of the empty space around you.

Answer (score 1):

The space was gigantic (unnaturally big). We felt dwarfed (made unnaturally small) by the space.

dwarf
(verb).
past tense: dwarfed; past participle: dwarfed
**cause to seem small or insignificant in comparison.**

"the buildings surround and dwarf All Saints church"